# Что такое чертог?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Чертогами высокопарно называют помпезные строения, вроде дворцов или замков. Также чертогами почему-то называют некие загробные обиталища, вроде Валхаллы или чего-то подобного. Викисловарь говорит так: "Чертог - устаревшее, большое богатое помещение, палата". У Лермонтова читаем:
*Всечасно дивною игрою

Твой слух лелеять буду я;

Чертоги пышные построю

Из бирюзы и янтаря.*

Так все-таки, что такое чертог и, главное, мне интересно, родственник ли он слову "черта"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В киевском издании Лексикона славеноросского Памвы Берынды (1653) слово *чертог* объясняется так :

> **Чрътогъ**. Ложница або покой, кролевский палацъ, теремъ, полата царева зготованая.

В Церковном словаре 1773/1815 *чертог* - спальня или (иногда) нечто вроде *амвона*, возвышенное великое место, где короновали царей. 
Все более поздние словари пишут примерно то же самое.
Семантика слова : закрытое внутреннее помещение, царская опочивальня, богато украшенная, с правом входа только самым ближним и доверенным.
Предполагается тюркское происхождение; однако я бы оставил версию **черты**... Сопоставьте : *порог* и *чертог*. Порог - граница помещения.

> **ПОРОГ**
> Это слово, называющее брусок, закрывающий проем в полу под дверью, восходит к той же основе, что и глагол пороть ("разрезать, раздирать"), и образовано от этого глагола с помощью суффикса гъ; первоначально – "то, что находится на стыке, в месте разреза". (Этим. слов. Крылова)

Если порог - граница, то чертог может быть "запретным местом", только для царственных особ.
(в качестве личной версии)

Comment: Есть  ещё  и  чердак.  Тюркского  происхождения.

Comment: Против тюркского чердака возражать не буду, но отмечу первоначальную форму слова : *чардакъ* (пространство между потолком и кровлей). Между *чертогом* и *чердаком* - значительные различия в семантике и морфологии, согласитесь.

Comment: Чердаком  в  былинах  назывались  ещё  и  помещения ( на  палубе ) на  кораблях  Садко.

Answer (score 3):

1. Чертог. Это слово, имеющее значение "дворец", вероятно, является заимствованием из тюркских, восходящим к персидскому первоисточнику «cartak» (словарь Г. А. Крылова).
2. Из словаря М. Фасмера:
   черто́г род. п. -а, мн. черто́ги, укр. черто́г "внутренняя часть здания" (и то и другое заимств. из цслав.), ст.-слав. чрътогъ θάλαμος др.-сербск. чртог, чртаг – то же. Вероятно, через др.-булг. посредство заимств. из перс. čārtāk (čār "четыре" + tāk "высокая, выступающая часть дома, портик, балкон"); см. Мi. ЕW 35, ТЕl. I, 240, 273; Мелиоранский, ИОРЯС 10, 4, 133; Корш, Jagić-Festschrift 255; Младенов, RЕS I, 51; Локоч 32. Более поздним заимствованием является форма черда́к (см.). Невероятно объяснение слова чьртогъ как исконпослав. и сближение с черту, вопреки Брюкнеру (KZ 46, 237).
3. Шанский Н. М. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. Чертог. Др.-рус. заимств. из тюрк. яз., где оно является иранизмом. См. чердак.

Comment: Изначальное значение слова *чертог* - "спальная/свадебная комната". Дворцы потом уже придумались (метонимия, когда *часть* заменяет *целое*)...

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то я склонен думать, что и 'чертог', и 'чердак' этимологически восходят к иранским языкам. 'Чер' — четыре, 'тог' — арка(стена с аркой). И поскольку слово 'чертог' в русском языке имеет значение 'жилище, обиталище', то слова 'четыре стены'(пусть даже с аркой) вполне подходят по контексту.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно происходит от слова "черта", связано со словами родственных языков, "рубец", "надрез", "чертог" (черта, грань, порог). Буквально бесчисленные чертоги, где чертогами можно назвать крыльцо строения, жилища.